# Magento 2 : How to get DefaultBillingAddress using knockout?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, billing-address

In core using KO address is get like this in details.html file

```
    <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().prefix --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().firstname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().middlename --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().lastname --><!-- /ko --> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().suffix --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: _.values(currentBillingAddress().street).join(", ") --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().city --><!-- /ko -->, <span data-bind="html: currentBillingAddress().region"></span> <!-- ko text: currentBillingAddress().postcode --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko text: getCountryName(currentBillingAddress().countryId) --><!-- /ko --><br/>
<!-- ko if: (currentBillingAddress().telephone) -->
```

This is currentbillingaddress but i want to get defaultbillingaddress in the same way this is, someone any idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI component `Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address` doesn't expose the defaultBillingAddress property to the html template, we need to create a new one for that.

Please see the screenshot and try the full code of the billing-address.js below:
[image: here]

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'ko',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-billing-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address',
    'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList',
    'mage/translate',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator'
],
function (
    ko,
    _,
    Component,
    customer,
    addressList,
    quote,
    createBillingAddress,
    selectBillingAddress,
    checkoutData,
    checkoutDataResolver,
    customerData,
    setBillingAddressAction,
    globalMessageList,
    $t,
    shippingRatesValidator
) {
    'use strict';

    var lastSelectedBillingAddress = null,
        newAddressOption = {
            /**
             * Get new address label
             * @returns {String}
             */
            getAddressInline: function () {
                return $t('New Address');
            },
            customerAddressId: null
        },
        countryData = customerData.get('directory-data'),
        addressOptions = addressList().filter(function (address) {
            return address.getType() == 'customer-address'; //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
        });

        var defaultBillingAddresses = addressList().filter(function (address) {
            return  address.getType() == 'customer-address' && address.isDefaultBilling();
        });

    addressOptions.push(newAddressOption);

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/billing-address'
        },
        currentBillingAddress: quote.billingAddress,
        addressOptions: addressOptions,
        customerHasAddresses: addressOptions.length > 1,
        defaultBillingAddress: ko.observable(defaultBillingAddresses[0]),

        /**
         * Init component
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            quote.paymentMethod.subscribe(function () {
                checkoutDataResolver.resolveBillingAddress();
            }, this);
            shippingRatesValidator.initFields(this.get('name') + '.form-fields');
        },

        /**
         * @return {exports.initObservable}
         */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe({
                    selectedAddress: null,
                    isAddressDetailsVisible: quote.billingAddress() != null,
                    isAddressFormVisible: !customer.isLoggedIn() || addressOptions.length === 1,
                    isAddressSameAsShipping: false,
                    saveInAddressBook: 1
                });

            quote.billingAddress.subscribe(function (newAddress) {
                if (quote.isVirtual()) {
                    this.isAddressSameAsShipping(false);
                } else {
                    this.isAddressSameAsShipping(
                        newAddress != null &&
                        newAddress.getCacheKey() == quote.shippingAddress().getCacheKey() //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                    );
                }

                if (newAddress != null && newAddress.saveInAddressBook !== undefined) {
                    this.saveInAddressBook(newAddress.saveInAddressBook);
                } else {
                    this.saveInAddressBook(1);
                }
                this.isAddressDetailsVisible(true);
            }, this);

            return this;
        },

        canUseShippingAddress: ko.computed(function () {
            return !quote.isVirtual() && quote.shippingAddress() && quote.shippingAddress().canUseForBilling();
        }),

        /**
         * @param {Object} address
         * @return {*}
         */
        addressOptionsText: function (address) {
            return address.getAddressInline();
        },

        /**
         * @return {Boolean}
         */
        useShippingAddress: function () {
            if (this.isAddressSameAsShipping()) {
                selectBillingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());

                this.updateAddresses();
                this.isAddressDetailsVisible(true);
            } else {
                lastSelectedBillingAddress = quote.billingAddress();
                quote.billingAddress(null);
                this.isAddressDetailsVisible(false);
            }
            checkoutData.setSelectedBillingAddress(null);

            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Update address action
         */
        updateAddress: function () {
            var addressData, newBillingAddress;

            if (this.selectedAddress() && this.selectedAddress() != newAddressOption) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                selectBillingAddress(this.selectedAddress());
                checkoutData.setSelectedBillingAddress(this.selectedAddress().getKey());
            } else {
                this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
                this.source.trigger(this.dataScopePrefix + '.data.validate');

                if (this.source.get(this.dataScopePrefix + '.custom_attributes')) {
                    this.source.trigger(this.dataScopePrefix + '.custom_attributes.data.validate');
                }

                if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                    addressData = this.source.get(this.dataScopePrefix);

                    if (customer.isLoggedIn() && !this.customerHasAddresses) { //eslint-disable-line max-depth
                        this.saveInAddressBook(1);
                    }
                    addressData['save_in_address_book'] = this.saveInAddressBook() ? 1 : 0;
                    newBillingAddress = createBillingAddress(addressData);

                    // New address must be selected as a billing address
                    selectBillingAddress(newBillingAddress);
                    checkoutData.setSelectedBillingAddress(newBillingAddress.getKey());
                    checkoutData.setNewCustomerBillingAddress(addressData);
                }
            }
            this.updateAddresses();
        },

        /**
         * Edit address action
         */
        editAddress: function () {
            lastSelectedBillingAddress = quote.billingAddress();
            quote.billingAddress(null);
            this.isAddressDetailsVisible(false);
        },

        /**
         * Cancel address edit action
         */
        cancelAddressEdit: function () {
            this.restoreBillingAddress();

            if (quote.billingAddress()) {
                // restore 'Same As Shipping' checkbox state
                this.isAddressSameAsShipping(
                    quote.billingAddress() != null &&
                        quote.billingAddress().getCacheKey() == quote.shippingAddress().getCacheKey() && //eslint-disable-line
                        !quote.isVirtual()
                );
                this.isAddressDetailsVisible(true);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Restore billing address
         */
        restoreBillingAddress: function () {
            if (lastSelectedBillingAddress != null) {
                selectBillingAddress(lastSelectedBillingAddress);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param {Object} address
         */
        onAddressChange: function (address) {
            this.isAddressFormVisible(address == newAddressOption); //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
        },

        /**
         * @param {Number} countryId
         * @return {*}
         */
        getCountryName: function (countryId) {
            return countryData()[countryId] != undefined ? countryData()[countryId].name : ''; //eslint-disable-line
        },

        /**
         * Trigger action to update shipping and billing addresses
         */
        updateAddresses: function () {
            if (window.checkoutConfig.reloadOnBillingAddress ||
                !window.checkoutConfig.displayBillingOnPaymentMethod
            ) {
                setBillingAddressAction(globalMessageList);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Get code
         * @param {Object} parent
         * @returns {String}
         */
        getCode: function (parent) {
            return _.isFunction(parent.getCode) ? parent.getCode() : 'shared';
        }
    });
});*
```

After that, on the billing-address/details.html you can use

> **defaultBillingAddress().firstname, defaultBillingAddress().lastname**

, etc

Comment: thanks man that helped alot

Answer (score 1):

I was messing around with plugins to pass additional customer info through to knockout. I think you could do this

Xml

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/etc/di.xml

Plugin

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/Plugin/Magento/Customer/CustomerData/Customer.php

Template phtml

https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/index/index.phtml#L19-L24

Comment: i just need to over write this file that i already did it but don't know how to call DefaultBillingAddress method using KO

Comment: See how I added to array https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/Plugin/Magento/Customer/CustomerData/Customer.php#L46 and then checked for value in phtml https://github.com/DominicWatts/CustomerLogin/blob/master/view/frontend/templates/index/index.phtml#L19